# Python script how can it do short

Tags: python, file-io

I have written a script on a python "icecast server", and I changed some strings in "/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml" like this:

```
import os,sys,re
def ices2():
    changedir=open(pathh + "icecast3.xml", "w")
    data=open("/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml").read()
    changedir.write(re.sub("<source-password>hackme</source-password>","<source-password>123</source-password>" % x,data))
    changedir.close()
ices2()
def ices1():
    changedir1=open(pathh + "icecast2.xml", "w")
    data=open(pathh + "icecast3.xml").read()
    changedir1.write(re.sub("<relay-password>hackme</relay-password>", "<relay-password>123</relay-password>" % x,data))
    changedir1.close()
    os.remove(pathh + "icecast3.xml")
ices1()
def ices():
    changedir2=open("/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml", "w")
    data=open(pathh + "icecast2.xml").read()
    changedir2.write(re.sub("<admin-password>hackme</admin-password>","<admin-password>123</admin-password>" % x,data))
    changedir2.close()
    os.remove(pathh + "icecast2.xml")
ices()
```

...but it's too long for the script. How can I shorten it? I need to do some changes in one file, open it to make changes and close it without any lost data.  I know that it can be done in one function, but how to do it I don't know.

I need three changes in one function like this:

```
def ices():
    changedir=open(pathh + "icecast3.xml", "w")
    data=open("/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml").read()
    changedir.write(re.sub("<source-password>hackme</source-password>","<source-password>123</source-password>",data))
    changedir1.write(re.sub("<relay-password>hackme</relay-password>", "<relay-password>123</relay-password>",data))
    changedir2.write(re.sub("<admin-password>hackme</admin-password>","<admin-password>123</admin-password>",data))
    changedir.close()
```

i did it in one function and my script short than upper one. But it's wrong i need do it correctly

```
changedir=open(pathh + "icecast3.xml", "w")
data=open("/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml").read()
```

Here I create a new file "pathh + "icecast3.xml" (pathh-/home/user/Downloads), but I need to open file:

```
"/etc/icecast2/icecast.xml"
```

...read it and write changes to the same file.

Answer (score 2):

All three functions do the same so you can join them into one. This is not complete solution but I think that you could go on from here on your own:

```
import os,sys,re
def ices(in_path, out_path, remove=False):
    changedir = open(out_path, "w")
    data = open(in_path, 'r')
    changedir.write(re.sub("<source-password>hackme</source-password>","<source-password>123</source-password>" % x,data.read())) # this is wrong as well but I take it as an example
    changedir.close()
    data.close()
    if remove:
        os.remove(in_path)
```

You can call this function with:

```
ices(base_path + 'icecast2.xml', base_path + 'icecast3.xml', True)
```

Hints:

- it's better to use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) for creating the full paths (as opposed to string concatenation)
- look at [`with` statement](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) and cosider using it for increased readability

**EDIT** (respecting the clarification in comment):

Sorry I missed the different strings in write. You can do it simply like this:

```
f =  open(filename, 'r')
data = f.read()
f.close()  
for tag in ['source', 'relay', 'admin']
    sub_str = "<{tag_name}>%s</{tag_name}>".format(tag_name=tag+'-password')
    data = re.sub(sub_str % 'hackme', sub_str % '123', data)
f = open(filename+'.new', 'w')
f.write(data)
f.close()
```

Comment: Example i have file icecast.xml i need change 3 strings in it. How to change three things in one function i don't know. I want to open file do some changes and write them in it.

Comment: Ah, I did not understood the question like that. I'll try to edit in a while.

Comment: O my english bad i'm sorry, i change question upper

Comment: ['source', 'relay', 'admin'] what we have to write in source relay admin?

Comment: @user1259251 Those are strings. I forgot to add the `-passsord` part. Edited again.